# How I can use onchange event on calender?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, calendar

I am using  `Joomla` calender and I want to perform some function `onChange` `event`, when i performed it disable the `datePicker` change functionality.

How I can use `onchange` `event` on calender ?

here is the code of calender :

`<field name="date" type="calendar"  required="true"  label="Select a date " description="" format="%Y-%m-%d" />`

Comment: Did you tried something like this $("input[name=date]").on('change', function() {
    alert('chnaged');
});

Comment: yes tried a lot , I think joomla's calender use onchange function itslef to pick a date

Comment: Which version of jquery using ?

Comment: its 1.10.2 but I don't think its version issue,

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add a class with attribute [options](http://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type).

```
<field name="date" class="mycalendar" type="calendar" required="true" label="Select a date " description="" format="%Y-%m-%d" />
```

The Use jQuery for tracking change event,

If you are using jQuery version above 1.7 like below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mycalendar").on('change', function() { alert('changed'); });
});
```

Your jQuery version <= 1.7 then try this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.mycalendar').live('change',function(){
        console.log('ss');
    });
});
```

This method should work I have tested.

Hope it helps..

Comment: thabks for reply , but its not working..

I am using 3.0, I have tested a lot ..
all events are working except 'change' .

Comment: @AliRaza - where are you adding this code to? Also, do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @AliRaza add the code inside you admin template or current layout and should enclosed with document(ready). It work

Comment: @Lodder I am testing it in browser console

Comment: @JobinJose right but if it should work in browser first

Comment: @AliRaza Yes, I test on fire-bug console its fine for me, did you run the code and changed the date on datepicker ? is it show any error?

Comment: no its showing no error but change events not working

Comment: @JobinJose i have test it with click event its working but for change its not, because joomla datepicker modifying it